# Confusion about sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read floats (and ints afterwards) from a line I'm getting out of a file. When I'm debugging it, I can see it's getting the line out of the file no problem, but when I try to sscanf it, I'm getting garbage. Here's my code:

```
    while(fgets(line, 1000, file) != EOF)
    {
        //Get the first character of the line
        c = line[0];

        if(c == 'v')
        {
            sscanf(line, "%f", &v1);
            printf("%f", v1);
        }
    }
```

The value stored in v1 is garbage. Why is this not working, and how can I get floats and ints out of this line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're including the first character (which is 'v') in the call to sscanf, so the call is failing and `v1` is left untouched (with garbage in it). Try this instead:

```
sscanf(line+1, "%f", &v1);
```

Comment: And, v1 was garbage because it was uninitialized. Check if sscanf actually initalized the arguments you give it, `if(sscanf(line+1, "%f", &v1)) != 1) { //error }`

Answer (score 2):

Presumably v1 is a float?

In which case printing a float in memory as if it was a 'c' string is going to be bad..
You might want to try `printf("%f",v1);`

```
    if(c == 'v')
    {
        sscanf(line, "%f", &v1);
```

If line starts with 'v' then you are sending that to scanf and asking it to convert it into a float? You probably want to move on a character (or more if you have other padding) and then start reading the float at line[1]?

Comment: Haha, thanks. But that was just there for debugging anyways. My real problem is v1 holds garbage. Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: In real code you should use strtod() if you have it - it can flag if the string isn't a valid float. looking at the code, you need to skip past the 'v' at the start of the line and send line[1] to sscanf()

Answer (score 1):

Your printf statement should look like this:

```
printf("%f\n", v1);
```

Also, you should check the return value of sscanf to check if it is even finding and storing the float:

```
if(sscanf(line, "%f", &v1) < 1){
    /* didn't read float */
}else{
    printf("%f\n", v1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know when you execute the `sscanf()` call that the first character in `line` is the letter 'v', you can also tell that there is no way that `sscanf()` can succeed in converting that to a `double` or `float` because 'v' is not part of any valid floating pointing number presented as a string.

You should check the return value from `sscanf()`; it would say 0 (no successful conversions), thereby telling you something has gone wrong.

You might succeed with:

```
if (sscanf(line+1, "%f", &v1) != 1)
    ...error...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your explanation is very clear. If I had done something like sscanf(line, "%s%f", v1) would that have been fine?

Comment: @Jeff: as written, no - `sscanf()` would try to copy the string to the float which would be horrid.  What might work is `sscanf(line, "%*s%f", &v1);` where the all-important `*` means 'do a conversion but do not assign it anywhere'.  Be aware that the `%*s` would skip a series of non-blank characters.  If the input string is `v 3.1416` (space after the 'v'), then this would work OK; if the input is `v3.1416` or `v+3.1416` (no space), then the number would be consumed as part of the string.

Comment: @Jeff - That would crash for a couple of reasons. First, you are passing `v1` instead of `&v1`. Second, you are specifying two format conversions but giving only one place to put them. You could use `sscanf(line, "v%f", &v1)`.

Comment: I realized right after I posted (and tested it) that it would just put it into the string. The * seems rather useful, and could be used in this case since there are spaces after the v's, but I think line+1 would be the better solution here.
@Ted Hopp: Yeah that would actually probably be better than using %*s%f